# AWS simple email service works on localhost but not on production Amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

So I am working on a mailing API for my website. The scenario is as follows:

1. Customer connects to endpoint.
2. API endpoint handles request and sends email using mailing service (which is based on aws sdk).
3. API returns Ok/BadRequest based on result.

When I am doing this with my API running on localhost everything works fine and I am receiving email on my mailbox as expected. But when I run my API service on Amazon EC2 instance I am getting this:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)

I double checked that I have .aws/credentials file both on my localhost machine and EC2 instance (ubuntu 16.10). I can reach my API service running on EC2 instance just fine, because I get the BadRequest response. The problem is when mailing service tries to send an email using amazon SES. I believe it's not the code itself because it runs fine on localhost. Any ideas?

Comment: For the record, I've updated my api code so now it sends emails using smtp protocol instead of aws sdk and it works as expected. So this is clearly an issue with aws sdk or some kind of missing configuration on my side. Anyways Im still looking for an answer.

Comment: Can you make any other API calls successfully (eg `ListTemplate()`) just to confirm that you have your credentials setup correctly? What is the value of the `region` in your configuration file or your code?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Every other API call is working just fine. Like I wrote before, I switched to sending emails using SMTP protocol and no problems so far. What kind of configuration file are you writing about? The AWS one? If yes, then I am not using any.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone else has the same problem, changing to port 587 solved the problem.

Ec2 has a very strict throttle on port 25 by default. You can get whitelisted on an IP-by-IP basis by filling out a formal request, but if you're sending to SES, our recommendation is to use port 587 or 2587.

For more on the EC2 throttle on port 25:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/

And for more about SES's available SMTP ports:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html